# How to Join Percentage ranges table and another Table:

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I have written Small Stored procedure it's giving below Results

```
Exec  dbo.usp_CDB_Percentile_V2 @input =10
```

Results :

```
percentile_Number   range1  Range2
1               1%  10%
2               11% 20%
3               21% 30%
4               31% 40%
5               41% 50%
6               51% 60%
7               61% 70%
8               71% 80%
9               81% 90%
10              91% 100%
```

another temp table has N no of rows reuslts are :

```
Person_Code       No'of contacts         Percentile(%)
AAA1                44                     35.77
AAA2                88                     71.5

AA3                 123                     100%
```

I am trying to create a dashboard so how can I join the both tables using T-SQL Code... 
Can you please give me advise I will grateul to you. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you writing a stored procedure to do something that SQL Server already does (`ntile()` and `percentile_rank()`)?  Second, if you want to write your own, why not use a table valued function instead of a stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

I would let the SP to only return a float number instead of a percentage. I would add the percentage symbol in my View.

Then it would be easy to join the results with the table:

```
DECLARE @Ranges AS Table(percentile_Number INT, range1 FLOAT, range2 FLOAT)
INSERT INTO @Ranges
Exec dbo.usp_CDB_Percentile_V2 @input =10

SELECT *
FROM   Persons P
       JOIN @Ranges R ON P.Percentile BETWEEN R.range1 AND R.range2
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you may not need the stored procedure at all. Check the NTILE() function:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175126.aspx

At least it does the same as your stored procedure.